# Android ACTION_CALL not working

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-permissions

for some reason ACTION_CALL is not working in my app. I have added the permission to the manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Here is where I call action_call from my main activity:

```
case R.id.button2:
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:(+44)12345678900"));
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(this, "No permission to call!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
startActivity(intent);
            break;
```

Each time the toast shows and the number is not called. Any help would be appreciated! :)

manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.adamw_000.lab_1_intents" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: Please show the code where you are calling `requestPermissions()`, to ask the user for this permission. Also, are you sure that you have your `<uses-permission>` element in the proper spot in the manifest? BTW, I suggest removing the space in the `tel:` string, as that might confuse the dialer, when you get to that point.

Comment: Have removed the space and added the code for the manifest permissions, I don't call request permission as the permission is already given in the manifest

Comment: "I don't call request permission as the permission is already given in the manifest" -- then that's your bug. The point behind calling `checkSelfPermission()` is to see if the user granted the permission. On Android 6.0, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher, you do *not* get this permission automatically and need to request it. See the duplicate question for more details.

Comment: Im using api 22 edit: nvm i see where you're going with this cheers

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should add the `startActivity()` as

```
startActivity(intent);
```

### EDIT

I used this code :

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel: (+44)12345678900"));
startActivity(intent);
```

And it works well...

Try this, it is working as well for me but it's using `ACTION_DIAL`:

```
public static Intent newPhoneCallIntent(String phoneNumber){
    Intent callintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    callintent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phoneNumber));
    return callintent;
}
```

And in your `Button` add this : `startActivity(newPhoneCallIntent("(+44)12345678900"));`

Comment: oops my bad! was already there missed that line when copying have added it in now

Comment: @AdamW95 see mye dit please

Comment: The problem was that the user has to give permission on api 23+, thanks though :)

Comment: @AdamW95  
So my answer didn't help to you? I delete the answer or you accept it?

Comment: @AdamW95 you can write a detailed solution here as an answer. it would help a lot of people

Comment: At runtime:ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 0);